# Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions with segmented control

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

So, I have a segmented control to switch between to view controllers.
However, often, as soon as I switch, I get this message:

> Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions

Plus, after I get this, sometimes it happens that every object on the view disappear.

Here's the code:

```
func segmentValueChanged(sender: AnyObject) {


    if sender.selectedIndex == 0 {



        let newController = controllers.newController1
        let oldController = childViewControllers.last as UIViewController!


        self.container.frame.size.height = newController.view.frame.height


        oldController.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
        addChildViewController(newController)


        transitionFromViewController(oldController, toViewController: newController, duration: 0.9, options: .CurveLinear, animations:{ () -> Void in
            // nothing needed here


            }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in

                oldController.removeFromParentViewController()
                newController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)


        })

    } else if sender.selectedIndex == 1 {


        let newController = controllers.newController2
        let oldController = childViewControllers.last as UIViewController!

        oldController.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
        addChildViewController(newController)





        transitionFromViewController(oldController, toViewController: newController, duration: 0.9, options: .CurveLinear, animations:{ () -> Void in
            // nothing needed here

            }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in

                oldController.removeFromParentViewController()
                newController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)


        })
    }

}
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This line is backwards:

```
    self.container.frame.size.height = newController.view.frame.height
```

It is `newController`'s view's frame that you need to set!

Moreover, you are failing to *put* `newController.view` into the interface. That is why you end up without an interface.

Comment: Here is a working downloadable example of swapping child view controllers and their views: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/16eccf4d1a6003b2bb4032d4bd9131d0695846bd/bk2ch06p316containerController